# Push local branch into master

Tags: git, github

I have my Github project.
My idea is to have:

- Origin: contain latest prod version
- Master: contain all work changes before prod
- *all local branch*

I create new local branch called `logFaq`, I commit the code, and I want to push my `logFaq` branch into remote master.

What I tried is

```
> git push master logFaq

fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How I can solve it?
I want only to merge my local branch to remote master

If I perform from my local branch :

```
> git log
commit fcd2d97be1d69d9e3e79ca09ff725ec3eb083203 (HEAD -> logFaq)
Author: gdelle <-@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 6 09:05:56 2021 +0200

    aggiunto log apertura/chiusura faq

commit 4a4209b9e74618d62938503d4bf7934325a45541 (origin/master, origin/main, origin/HEAD, master, main)
Author: gdelle <-@MacBook-Pro-di-.local>
Date:   Fri Aug 6 07:56:31 2021 +0200

    my first commit
```

Comment: Basically, first merge your local branch into local master, then push master to the remote.

Comment: Ok how I can do it?

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll read it! if you answer the question I click as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you start by reading any of the most basic guides before using git. You can find many good resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) for a start.

For the question at hand, something along the lines of

```
git checkout master
git merge <your-branch-name-here>
git push
```

But beware of doing this without understanding what's going on, maybe try some commands in a sandbox repo a couple of times if needed. And **of course** if the repo is shared, be sure to know what kind of workflow is agreed upon.